# QuickBooks 14 Web Connector (QBWC) Samples

Tags: asp.net, quickbooks, qbwc

I am very newbie QBWC, I have downloaded sample (WCWebService-ASP.NET(C#)) from QB website and reviewing the "QBWC_proguide", but I am getting an error during add applicaiton in QBWC, that is invalid  when I add a qbxml(Add Customer) file.

Unxpected root doc:qbxml

QBWC1051: The new application was not added.

I have couple of questions.

1. is token ID return from QB? or shall we add and GUID?
2. I have seen some sample (WCWebservice) - buildRequest, this has CustomerQuery, InvoiceQuery and BillQuery, But I didnt get any reponse(I am doing some mistake here).
3. Do I need to generate a QWC file for every time to use in QBWC utility to "ADD APPLICATION".

Please advise me to achieve following process basically I am trying to populate Products from QB, and generate order from website again I should update the product count back to QB then Generate a Invoice from Website.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unxpected root doc:qbxml
>   QBWC1051: The new application was not added.

To troubleshoot the above error, you need to post your .QWC file so that we can see what you're doing.

Here's an example .QWC file:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Web_Connector_Overview#Example_.QWC_File

> is token ID return from QB? or shall we add and GUID?

You will choose a GUID OwnerID and FileID to put in the .QWC file.

Your web service may also use a GUID for a session token.

> I have seen some sample (WCWebservice) - buildRequest, this has CustomerQuery, InvoiceQuery and BillQuery, But I didnt get any reponse(I am doing some mistake here).

The response would come from QuickBooks. Your web service would then parse the response to do something with it.

You can see all available requests and responses by looking in the QuickBooks OSR:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

> Do I need to generate a QWC file for every time to use in QBWC utility to "ADD APPLICATION".

No. You will generate a .QWC file *once* for each QuickBooks company file you are connecting. The .QWC file essentially configures the Web Connector, and then after that it's already configured and will use the settings you loaded from the .QWC.

Comment: I have used the below .qwc file in QBWC   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
<AppName>NavaTest_HTTPWebService</AppName>
<AppID></AppID>
<AppURL>http://localhost/WCWebService/WCWebService.asmx</AppURL>
<AppDescription>SGD QB Web Service</AppDescription>
<AppSupport>http://localhost/WCWebService/WCWebService.asmx?wsdl</AppSupport>
<OwnerID>{87EDAAF8-637E-4203-867F-4BA79C2F8998}</OwnerID>
<FileID>{CA1C3EB8-1B61-4747-A743-8D5B438B83AC}</FileID>
<UserName>Nava</UserName>
<QBType>QBFS</QBType>
<Style>Document</Style>
<AuthFlags>0xF</AuthFlags>
</QBWCXML> -It's working fine.

Comment: Now can you please help me out? that is How can I get the list product from QB?  for that I have tried like the below <QBXML>

    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">

        <ItemQueryRq requestID="1450">

            <MaxReturned>200</MaxReturned>

            <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>

        </ItemQueryRq>

    </QBXMLMsgsRq>

</QBXML> - now I am getting the error. Unexpected root element.

Comment: Post your Web Connector log and the full error message.